# Thrust Error: libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception. Abort trap: 6

Tags: macos, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, thrust

Trying to do a simple copy data from Host to Device using thrust. It's outputting:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Abort trap: 6
```

Code:

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
void test()
{
    thrust::host_vector<int> H(4);
    H[0] = 14;
    H[1] = 20;
    H[2] = 38;
    H[3] = 46;
    thrust::device_vector<int> D = H; // causing error
}
int main()
{
    test(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Here's how I compiled and ran it in OS X:

```
$ nvcc test.cu -o test
$ ./test
```

I have CUDA 5.5 installed which I believe installed Thrust 1.6.0 automatically.

Comment: What is your question? The code you have posted is perfectly valid and runs correctly if I try it on OS X with CUDA 5.0

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on mine. It's outputting that error above. Perhaps it's a bug with 5.5? I currently have the production release installed.

Comment: cuda 5.5 production release ships with thrust v1.7

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a bug in 5.5 production release. I uninstalled and reinstalled 5.0, everything works fine.

Comment: I'm not convinced.  I have cuda 5.5 production release installed and your code compiles and runs fine for me with no errors. Your code is pretty trivial, so it would be surprising indeed if there was a bug in thrust that accounted for it.

Comment: Not sure what else to say. I upgraded to 5.5 this morning, thrust stops working. Downgrade to 5.0, and it works.

Comment: which host c++ compiler are you using?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior with the [development version of Thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust)? Do normal CUDA programs run OK?

Comment: @RobertCrovella gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

Comment: @JaredHoberock I'm going to have to get back to you on that one.

Comment: @Ninja: What OS verion too - CUDA 5.5 is only supported on 10.7.5 and newer